# Python templating library that can treat '.' as non-special in parameter names?

Tags: open-source, library, python, templating

I would like to process templates which do not use `'.'` as a special character, so that parameter names like `foo.bar` are valid.  For my purposes a parameter name like that should mean that the parameter named `'foo.bar'` will be substituted into the template, and not, for example, that before substitution attribute `bar` will be looked up on the object referenced by parameter `foo`.

This is for a documentation application.

What is an appropriate Python library to do that?

Essential:

- Ability to treat `.` as non-special in template parameter names -- because there is a flat key/value set of parameters to be substituted, whose names contain that character
- Precise and convenient control over whitespace -- because may be generating e.g. markdown or ReST files
- Ability to substitute some string for missing parameters rather than erroring or halting generation of output (the empty string would be OK, bonus points for customizable string) -- because the documentation authoring tool I am writing will make these missing parameters obvious, but an error would hinder the process of documentation writing
- Good template error reporting (syntax errors and runtime errors)

Other useful features / qualities in approximate order of importance:

- Robust / polished
- `{{}}` syntax -- because we use this syntax in our codebase already
- Good support for escaping
- Relatively simple
- Fast
- Unicode support

Unimportant:

- Sandboxing
- Template inheritance